# How to extract data from a data set in python

Tags: python, string

```
import pandas as pd
from smartapi import SmartConnect
from smartapi import SmartWebSocket
import json
obj = SmartConnect(api_key="vhidyTNq")

refreshToken = data['data']['refreshToken']
feedToken = obj.getfeedToken()
ss = SmartWebSocket(feedToken,"P78013")
 
obj=SmartConnect(api_key="vhidyTNq")
data = obj.generateSession("P78013","Ujhdy@2")
print(data)

parsed = json.loads(data)

print(parsed.jwtToken)
```

The result printed in the following format

> {'status': True, 'message': 'SUCCESS', 'errorcode': '', 'data':
> {'clientcode': 'K98913', 'name': 'HPP', 'email': '',
> 'mobileno': '', 'exchanges': ['bse_cm', 'cde_fo', 'mcx_fo', 'ncx_fo',
> 'nse_cm', 'nse_fo'], 'products': ['CNC', 'NRML', 'MARGIN', 'MIS',
> 'BO', 'CO'], 'lastlogintime': '', 'broker': '', 'jwtToken': 'Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Iko4ODkxMyIsInJvbGVzIjowLCJ1c2VydHlwZSI6IlVTRVIiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTU3NTAxNDksImV4cCI6MTc0MjE1MDE0OX0.P1Ne0T0lTgScZJ1udMYRaJ32WeNDB-bZIwMg4uSAGC4RDFnYRsdvXGRyIEx7KS1LpQ6ndRIt7UjoyIewCs7HLA',
> 'refreshToken':
> 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IlJFRlJFU0gtVE9LRU4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTU3NTAxNDl9.9DM1ggWfaervPe3qCpoDywfdb8kJ6okQrqZeR_mjsbGliqM7w0DdRyxTHyB7m-742Sfj9tVsZ4qQrOK0RQ9TmQ'}}

i am trying to filter out the 'jwtToken' value in the string format like below

jwtToken='Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI.....'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
print(parsed["data"]["jwtToken"])
```

Also, give the full code of your project will be appreciated.

Comment: I get the following error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

Comment: I updated the code now. Sorry for not testing your code. @jyotirmay

Answer (score 1):

Update:

It seems that `data` is a dict, then you can directly use `data['data']['jwtToken']` to get the result.

---

If `data` is a string, you can try using [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```py
import re
re.search(r"'jwtToken': '(.*?)'", data).group(1)
```